# How to aggregate multiple stages in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have following table and I'd like to sum and group by person and then aggregate its `time`

```
person   label value 
A      home  A       
A      plan  a 
A      plan  b      
A      time  3           
B      plan  a
B      time  4      
C      plan  b           
C      time  5
```

person `A` has plan `a` and `b`

person `B` has plan `a`

person `C` has plan `b`

so that My desired result is like follows

```
plan sum(time) 
a      7
b      8
```

As a progress , I come up with following one.

```
select 
person,
case when label in('plan') then value else null end as plan,
sum(case when label in ('time') then value else 0 end) as sum(time)
```

Are there any way to achieve desired result ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can simply JOIN to the table to obtain the times:

```sql
SELECT
  plan.person,
  SUM(time.value)
FROM table plan
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE label='time') time USING (person)
WHERE label = 'home'
```

You'll probably need some tweaking to handle the fact that `person` appears in uppercase but `value` appears in lowercase.